# How to create a countdown in rails (ultimatum) without javascript

Tags: ruby-on-rails, time

How can I create an ultimatum in Rails?

I want to create an ultimatum, and at the end of it, update an attribute like `treated: true` (exemples [sic] below).

I tried:

```
a = Time.new
# => 2018-07-17 10:16:23 +0200
b = 2.days.after
# => Thu, 19 Jul 2018 08:16:27 UTC +00:00
a - b
# => -172804.182368
b - a
# => 172804.182368
c = b - a
# => 172804.182368
t = Time.at(c)
# => 1970-01-03 01:00:04 +0100
```

But it's not working. Some solutions please?

#### Exemples [sic]

Imagine a marketplace (like amazon) that have sellers.

First exemple [sic]:
A seller receives an order, and has 48 hours to act on it (switch state). At the and of the 48 hours, if the seller has not act, the order is canceled.

Second exemple [sic]:
A seller ships an order, and the delivery mod [sic] of the order has seven days to be received by the customer. And at the end of the lead time, the order state goes to "Receive".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use jobs for that.

Taking your first example, when order is created, create a job which would cancel order after two days:

```
CancelOrderJob.set(wait: 2.days).perform_later(order)
```

If seller acts on that order, you update attribute `fulfilled: true` of that order.

And to prevent cancellation of fulfilled orders, you could just do nothing when job is executed:

```
class CancelOrderJob < ApplicationJob
  queue_as :default

  def perform(order)
    order.cancel unless order.fulfilled?
  end
end
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks @rolandas